# Regular expression in Snowflake - starts with string and ends with digits

Tags: regex, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am struggling with writing regex expression in Snowflake.

```
SELECT
 'DEM7BZB01-123' AS SKU,
 RLIKE('DEM7BZB01-123','^DEM.*\d\d$') AS regex
```

I would like to find all strings that starts with "DEM" and ends with two digits. Unfortunately the expression that I am using returns FALSE.

[image]

I was checking this expression in two regex generators and it worked.

Answer (score 5):

In snowflake the backslash character `\` is an escape character.
Reference: [Escape Characters and Caveats](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions-regexp.html#label-regexp-escape-character-caveats)

So you need to use 2 backslashes in a regex to express 1.

```
SELECT
 'DEM7BZB01-123' AS SKU,
 RLIKE('DEM7BZB01-123', '^DEM.*\\d\\d$') AS regex
```

Or you could write the regex pattern in such a way that the backslash isn't used.

For example, the pattern `^DEM.*[0-9]{2}$` matches the same as the pattern `^DEM.*\d\d$`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape your backslashes in your SQL before it can be parsed as a regex string. (sometimes it gets a bit silly with the number of backslashes needed)

Your example should look like this

```sql
RLIKE('DEM7BZB01-123','^DEM.*\\d\\d$') AS regex
```

Comment: To add more to David point. `'^DEM.*\d\d$'` is a valid regexp in the real world, but to get those slashes past the SQL parser you need to escape them, thus they become double `\\`. Now if you are writing this SQL in a STORE PROCEDURE or FUNCTION that SQL get parse once when you enter the function, and a second time when it runs so a normal single slash needs to become 4 `\\\\` This a just a thing that happens in all parsed script from bash scripts to SQL.

Answer (score 0):

[`RLIKE`](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/rlike.html) (which is an alias in Snowflake for the SQL Standard `REGEXP_LIKE` function) implicitly adds `^` and `$` to your search pattern...

> The function implicitly anchors a pattern at both ends (i.e. '' automatically becomes '^$', and 'ABC' automatically becomes '^ABC$').

so you can remove them, and that then allows you to use `$$` [quoting](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions-regexp.html#specifying-regular-expressions-in-dollar-quoted-string-constants)

> In single-quoted string constants, you must escape the backslash character in the backslash-sequence. For example, to specify \d, use \d. For details, see Specifying Regular Expressions in Single-Quoted String Constants (in this topic).

> You do not need to escape backslashes if you are delimiting the string with pairs of dollar signs ($$) (rather than single quotes).

so you can simply use the regex `DEM.*\d\d` to find all strings that starts with `DEM` and ends with two digits without extra escaping as follows

```
SELECT
  'DEM7BZB01-123' AS SKU
, RLIKE('DEM7BZB01-123', $$DEM.*\d\d$$) AS regex
```

which gives

```
SKU          |REGEX|
-------------+-----+
DEM7BZB01-123|true |
```